# How to check the JSON format in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I will get the JSON Data like this. But I want to check whether key has an `Array` data or not. If It has 0 then skip. How can I check?

```
code = 200;
data =     {
    UserstoreReviewDetails = 0;
    storeReviewDetails = 0;
}
```

or

```
code = 200;
data =     {
    UserstoreReviewDetails = (
      {// array data}
    );
    storeReviewDetails =  (
      {// array data}
    );
}
```

I have tried like this. But getting an exception if data has an `Array` value.

```
[[self.jsonValue[@"data"] objectForKey:@"storeReviewDetails"]intValue] != 0

[[self.jsonValue[@"data"] objectForKey:@"storeReviewDetails"] isEqualToString:@"0"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// try like this

```
if([[[self.jsonValue[@"data"] objectForKey:@"storeReviewDetails"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
// data is array type
} else {
  //data is not an array type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
NSArray *array = [[self.jsonValue[@"data"] objectForKey:@"storeReviewDetails"];

if (array) {
    NSLog("StoreReviewDetails is array");
}
else {
    int count = [[self.jsonValue[@"data"] objectForKey:@"storeReviewDetails"]intValue];
}
```